# How to reconcile Singleton Pattern with Interface callback? - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, interface, singleton

Here is my situation:

- I have a printer that has a bluetooth connection with my scanner.
- The UI of the scanner must be updated based on the actions of the printer.

The fact that I have bluetooth connection makes me want to adopt the Singleton pattern, but the fact that I need a callback to the view makes me want to implement a interface.

However, I don't want to put any parameters in the constructor or the getInstance() method, as that would effectively be breaking the singleton principle.

My (really bad) idea I came up with was to create a setListener() function in the singleton class, and the view implementing the listener configures to singleton on startup. This feels...awful. Does anyone know a better way to bridge the two?

#### PrinterManager

```
class PrinterManager private constructor() {

    private lateinit var mListener: PrinterListener

    companion object {
        fun getInstance() = // ...
    }

    interface PrinterListener {
        fun showErrorDialog()
    }

    fun setListener(listener: PrinterListener) {
        mListener = listener
    }

    fun foo() {
        if (doSomething()) {
            // ...
        else {
            mListener.showErrorDialog()
        }
    }

}
```

#### MainActivity

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity(), PrinterManager.PrinterListener {

    override onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // ...
        PrinterManager.getInstance().setListener(this)
    }

    override fun showErrorDialog() {
        // ...
    }

}
```